# VOTE for the Most Valued Super User

Tags: discussion, super-contest, site-promotion

## Voting is over!

### Congratulations to Slhck, the 2011 MVSU! [Full contest results are posted on the Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/07/announcing-the-winners-of-the-super-user-anniversary-contest/).

In celebration of Super User's 2nd Anniversary, we are holding a Super User Contest to reward the most active, helpful, and involved members of our community. The grand prize will be awarded to one of **you** and chosen by *all* of you. Announcing...

## the *Most Valuable Super User* contest

The MVSU isn't just about reputation earned - it's about how much you've dedicated yourself to the community. Think of the users whose names you see helping the site out every day: editing, flagging, cleaning up, closing bad questions, and of course providing lots of great answers. Statistics are great, but we want *you*, the users of this site, to choose who you think has had the greatest positive impact on Super User.

There are a few rules, to ensure that users have met certain minimum criteria for what the judges think a Super Duper User ought to be, and to prevent there from being too many submissions to handle. **Users must meet these criteria *by the end of the competition***. You are welcome to nominate a user who does not have all of these things yet, as long as you believe they can in two weeks' time.

- At least **5k total rep** or **1k rep earned this year**.
- At least **200 flag weight**
- Earned the following **badges** (hover for requirements):

  [citizen patrol](https://superuser.com/badges/8/citizen-patrol),
  [enthusiast](https://superuser.com/badges/39/enthusiast),
  [suffrage](https://superuser.com/badges/89/suffrage),
  [tag editor](https://superuser.com/badges/63/tag-editor),
  [quorum](https://superuser.com/badges/95/quorum)
- Must be an overall **great person** to work with, and in good standing
- Currently **active on the site** (must visit and participate at some point during the contest)

Now we understand that you may not be able to view all of the exact statistics, but don't worry — we'll be monitoring each candidate to make sure they meet the criteria and are upstanding internet citizens. This portion of the contest is meant to bring attention to those dedicated users who keep this site running, and may not always get the credit they deserve. They truly are the most Super of Users.

---

## How nominations/voting works

Any registered user may nominate any other user (except for contest judges/♦ mods), providing the candidate meets the above criteria, or likely will by the end of the competition. You may not enter yourself in the competition.

Nominations should be entered as a single answer with the user's name, and a link to their profile. Include their SU image flair so we can get an idea for what they've done. **All commentary, endorsements, etc. should go in the comments below the answer**. Use this template:

```
#[Username][7]

[![Username][8]][9]

[1]: https://superuser.com/users/SUPERUSER_ID
[2]: https://superuser.com/users/flair/SUPERUSER_ID.png
```

***for example...***

> ## [Jeff Atwood](https://superuser.com/users/1)
>
> [image: kronos]

The user with the highest vote score (total score, `upvotes - downvotes`) at the end of the contest (providing they meet all criteria) will win the Super User Contest Grand Prize. The second and third place Super Users will receive Level 3 prizes. The next 7 runner-ups will receive a Super User t-shirt.

<sub>Note that judges/moderators have final say in the contest - any decisions regarding users deemed disqualified are final.</sub>

Comment: Perhaps a silly question given the judging, but can we nominate moderators for this?

Comment: @Gareth as explained under "how nominations/voting works", it says you may register any other user _except for contest judges_. All SU moderators are judging the contest, so no, you cannot nominate us (or rather if you did, we would not be eligible to win). Sorry ;)

Comment: Thanks! It's Monday morning so that escaped me. ;) Appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Happy birthday!!

Comment: +1 We should have more of these MVSU threads, receiving feedback is awesome... :)

Comment: @Tom Wijsman:  ...and it's "awesome" because it strengthens that wonderful _feeling of community_ I've noticed seems to be developing around here.

Comment: I do hope that for any downvotes that occur, that the downvoters also add a comment that provides a reason since this could be helpful to the community in a constructive way (I certainly have a desire to improve, and knowing where I might be going wrong may help me with that).

Comment: ... Is Kronos part of the question / Does my upvote here count for him, or should I open a new nomination for him?

Comment: @WilliamHilsum Kronos is ineligible, because he is one of the judges. He was used as an example. I changed the example to a different user to make it more obvious that it's not a contestant.

Comment: Had no idea he was a judge! Thanks for saying! (or sorry, I didn't read better!)... Now... Can I vote for Jeff then by voting here :P

Comment: God bless everyone that made the best knowledge sharing system in the world possible

Comment: A shame that there weren't more comments on why someone downvotes. I'm sure the nominees would have appreciated that. These are all excellent contributors that would take criticism to further improve themselves.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## [slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078)

[image: slhck]

Comment: slhck is great for his editing, ability to find content quickly, and nails duplicates like a boss. I would +2 this if I could

Comment: slhck is very welcoming to new users and makes the effort to help guide them towards asking better questions. I've also seen him often adding detail to existing answers, such as screenshots, which is beneficial to the site.

Comment: Been wanting to nominate you! For all the reasons mentioned above and all the other great effort you put in maintaining our beloved community I award slhck house with one point. Hurray!

Comment: +1, slhck is a very knowledgeable member in the community, and contributes quite a bit (in terms of edits, answers, and quality).  Good luck man, I hope you win MVSU!

Comment: +1 from me, there is barely a question I answer where I haven't seen your name retagging or doing something!

Comment: +1 from me. He's very knowledgeable and contributes even more in terms of editing, retagging and whatnot.

Comment: I totally agree, especially for his great attitude and *heroic* stamina. He's always very polite, patient, and encouraging to new users.

Comment: @slhck don't forget to edit some tag wikis before the contest is over, to satisfy the eligibility requirements!

Comment: Also mind you, just because a tag wiki already exists, doesn't mean its as helpful as it could be!

Comment: @Ivo Trying my best to improve where I can ;)

Comment: May I note that on most flags I act on have been rendered invalid, because @slhck stepped up and made it into a useful post. Job well done!

Comment: Shhhh — don't tell, someone might be upset! :P @Ivo

Comment: @Ivo somebody should list you, besides the fact that you have a lot of rep, so you must be contributing a lot, you've also made the effort to change your previous highly disturbing avatar, to one that is still very disturbing (a man giving the viewer/me, a big bright gleaming smile like a girl, and staring through the screen at me), but somewhat less disturbing than the previous one.

Comment: @barlop amusing perhaps, but Ivo isn't eligible because he is a moderator.

Comment: +1 he answered my question really well, he explained it to me as if i was a beautiful princess

Answer (score 40):

## [BloodPhilia](https://superuser.com/users/34844)

[image: BloodPhilia]

Comment: In my opinion one of the nicest and happiest persons around here!

Comment: @slhck Aw thanks! :D You're making me blush!

Comment: Oh wow, 14 votes! I love you guys! Now start voting for @slhck! :P

Comment: This really is _the cat's meow of Q&A web sites_, isn't it?

Comment: @RandolRichardson "The cat's meow"? What's that D:?

Comment: @BloodPhilia:  "The cat's meow" is an _idiom_ that essentially refers to something that's excellent or wonderful.

Comment: @RandolRichardson That's quite the cat's meow of idoms now isn't it! I love it! I'll be using this all the time now. :D

Comment: 32 votes!? I feel much appreciated!

Comment: @BloodPhilia:  I see 34 upvotes and 1 downvote, which tells me that you've had _a positive effect_ on 34 people (including me), and _a not-so-positive effect_ on 1.  In total, you've had an effect on 35 people, congratulations!  ;-)

Comment: @RandolRichardson Thanks for all the calculations! Now I feel even more so appreciated! ;) And thanks for your upvote of course!

Answer (score 31):

## [Gareth](https://superuser.com/users/73637)

[image: Gareth]

Comment: I see a lot of contributions through edits, which improve the overall quality of the content (Questions and Answers) on this web site.

Comment: Oh yeah, one more thing, Gareth's avatar always makes me laugh!  The way he's holding his hands around his eyes kind of makes him look like an Owl.  =D

Comment: In addition to single handedly waging a battle against image-lin rot, Gareth somehow manages to find the time to improve posts (by other users) with screenshots. I'd be remiss if i didn't upvote him ;p

Comment: Thanks everyone for the kind comments and upvotes, and particularly Randolf for nominating me! I am really more than grateful. I only hope that my edits help improve Super User: whether a complete rewrite of a question for clarity, or a simple reupload of an image to prevent link rot! I love the community spirit here. :)

Answer (score 31):

## [William Hilsum](https://superuser.com/users/4386)

[image: William Hilsum]

Comment: Contributes detailed, informative answers, and comments are often constructive (e.g., suggesting to a user that they update their question or answer in a meaningful way).

Comment: I think Wil would solve *any* computer problem for you!

Comment: Wil is a very positive member of the community, always looking on the bright side. He's always willing to help, and give up his time to troubleshoot your problem. He's great to talk to in chat, a welcoming person to the community

Comment: +1 a member who I think adds to Super User in a lot of ways.

Comment: Alien. Here's my vote.

Comment: I don't really get the Alien comment! Apart from that... I just wanted to say thank you very much to **everyone** who has upvoted me, I am happy to have helped you and hope to continue doing it for a long time to come! ... In addition, I don't get why there are so many down votes :( If I have done anything to annoy anyone, I am truly very sorry :( - If I have really annoyed you, please send me an (anonymous) email and I will (try to) change my ways! I just don't know what I have done to annoy people!

Comment: I'm wondering, and hoping, that the downvotes are simply from people who want 'their man' to win and so downovote people they percive to be competition. I have always found your answers very helpful and complete since I started using the site. +1 from me.

Comment: Will has spent time voice chatting with me over Skype at 4AM his time! Most Valued SuperUser in my book!

Comment: @Moshe:  Awesome!  SuperUser.com comes with live, personalized, technical support!  =)

Comment: I can't thank him enough for the time he spent helping me over Skype and TeamViewer today! Brilliant work, and helped a Mac guy like me learn SO much about Windows!

Answer (score 29):

## [Daniel Beck](https://superuser.com/users/22317)

[image: Daniel Beck]

Comment: Excellent contributor to all things OS X, among other things.

Comment: Currently about 7% of the accepted answers for [tag:osx] are posted by DB. ([232](http://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A22317+%5Bosx%5D+isaccepted%3A1&submit=search) out of [3464](http://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bosx%5D+isaccepted%3A1&submit=search).) The number of votes is unfairly low at the moment because this is the most recently posted entry.

Comment: Definitely more votes for DB -- always comes up with great answers and own solutions.

Comment: Thank you all very much for all the up votes! I never would have imagined a result even remotely like this. I just enjoy helping people with using the technology I love. Getting feedback like this is amazing and I appreciate it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 25):

## [Journeyman Geek](https://superuser.com/users/10165)

[image: journeyman-geek]

Comment: Contributes great content in answers, comments, wiki entries, and tags.

Comment: I will +1 this simply because he's a friend and I respect his knowledge, but also he introduced me to this site. But even still, as a friend, I know what he deals with back home, so it's even more impressive that he's able to amass the knowledge and experience he has. He's one of my go-to people for techy questions. :)

Comment: Thanks guys ^^ I appreciate the commments, and being in the running is just gravy, since I've already gotten so much neat knowledge (and a place to look up, and ask stuff that stumps me) from the community.

Answer (score 16):

## [techie007](https://superuser.com/users/23133)

[image: techie007]

Comment: *Always* quick to find a duplicate, and writes tons of helpful answers!

Comment: <blush> Thanks slhck. :)

Answer (score 14):

## [Tom Wijsman](https://superuser.com/users/9666)

[image: Tom Wijsman]

Comment: I like the quality of detail in Tom's answers and comments.

Comment: Not to forget all those edits for our famous questions -- keep up the good work!

Comment: +1 I have learnt quite a bit from your questions on diagnosing/performance tools and similar! Very worthy for this award!

Comment: He puts a lot of effort into his posts, as well as the SU blog.

Answer (score 14):

## [Randolf Richardson](https://superuser.com/users/26312/randolf-richardson)

[image: Randolf Richardson]

Comment: +1 a) for nominating me, b) I have backed down quite a few times because there has been a good answer from you / or significantly edited what I was going to say!

Answer (score 13):

## [Breakthrough](https://superuser.com/users/6887/breakthrough)

[image: Breakthrough]

Comment: He has recently reached 10k (congratulations again!) -- I like that his answers are always very technical and to the point.

Answer (score 13):

## [KCotreau](https://superuser.com/users/83981/kcotreau)

[image: kcotreau]

Comment: kcotreau always has friendly and constructive answers that don't merely support the technical knowledge of the community but also the relational aspect of this site. People who feel appreciated and understood are more likely to come back frequently, continuing their involvement in this site.

Comment: He told us he was leaving the site and no longer returning

Comment: Ah, that is sad to hear.

Comment: Indeed, if you check his profile you can see why.

Comment: `I have enjoyed helping many of you, but I am done here simply because of moderator Random. I will not be a part of a place that allows someone in charge to be unfair, and a bully, and when you question it, they ostracize you.`

Comment: I found many of @KCotreau's answers to be valuable.  KCotreau also gained a lot of points over a very short time-period, which reminds me of the "Achiever" player types on many MMORPGs (Massive Multi-User Online Role Playing Games) who "level up" as quickly as possible, but the difference here is that one must contribute in a meaningful way to really earn all those upvotes.

Comment: -1, I'm afraid. Would be +1 if he was still around, or had left for other reasons. He was indeed a formidable contributor in his answers, but I don't appreciate his attitude towards one of our valued moderators (which he goes as far as calling by name), neither I'm particularly friendly to listing my own achievements as if these somehow should legitimate my ad hominem attack on that moderator. His profile reveals a type of contributor I don't appreciate.

Comment: Reading his "farewell" just now I think I can appreciate where he's coming from. I've had my own run-ins and disagreements. I suppose he and I would differ at where the value outweighs the problems, and possibly again at how change is to be made, from the inside or the outside.

Comment: I think there's usually three sides to every disagreement -- the first person, the second person, and the truth.  The way I see this situation is that we're only seeing one side of it.  I don't agree with airing this sort of thing publicly, especially in the manner that this user did (which causes me to question the reliability of his statement), but that doesn't change my view on the value of his answers.

Comment: Since a lot is being said about me, I thought I would comment. You may not like what I said, or how I said it, but ultimately, the owner of this site agreed in an e-mail that my issues were valid. I felt I could do no right with the moderator in question, and things that I flagged, and marked by him as invalid (even things that I could not just flag or do anything about myself), were ultimately handed EXACTLY as I flagged them. The guy was unfair, and yes, I have a problem with that. In case you wonder why I am even here: I have considered returning, but did not wish to restart the 100 days.

Comment: @music2myear I really am appreciative of your nomination, and thank you as it means a lot to me. I also thank those, who upvoted.

Comment: For the sake of completeness and fairness: the moderator in question did offer a truce with @KCotreau, stating that henceforth he would defer all decisions on KCotreau's flags to other moderators to avoid further perceptions of unfairness from that moderator.

Comment: @nhinkle♦ "For the sake of completeness and fairness", it seemed like he was ordered to do so, and he never really apologized, which would have made a difference.

Comment: Let's try not to fall into another discussion of who is right or wrong. Fact is KCotreau has contributed a lot to the communnity and yet has had a few issues with the moderation. All parties involved are human and make mistakes. This contest is meant to build the community and recognize those that truly contribute. Let's stick to that attitude instead.

Comment: KCotreau, to my knowledge, he did so of his own volition. That being said, I agree with @KronoS that we should move on and respect the spirit of the competition. You've made many valuable contributions to the site, and I think we all hope that you can return with a positive outlook and put past misunderstandings behind us.

Answer (score 13):

## [Moab](https://superuser.com/users/40928)

[image: Moab]

Answer (score 12):

## [soandos](https://superuser.com/users/82812)

[image: soandos]

Comment: For being active on Meta, cleaning up the tags and synonyms, flagging, and always instantly asking for clarification when needed in questions.

Comment: Thanks for the nomination. I don't I will be able to win though, as I will be unable to get the enthusiast badge (UTC and sundown on the east cost of the US are just too close this time of year) not to mention there are much better users out there. Nomination means a lot though, so thanks.

Answer (score 11):

## [yhw42](https://superuser.com/users/45662)

[image: yhw42]

Comment: for those wondering, yhw has been one of the earliest people to make use of suggested edits and flags. Interview of him on [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/20/to-flag-or-not-to-flag/)