# Would a "personal feedback" question be appropriate on Meta.SU?

Tags: discussion

From the [MVSU Meta question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3186/vote-for-the-most-valued-super-user) I liked getting feedback from my fellow users and so did Tom Wijsman as I understand from his comment to the question:

> +1 We should have more of these MVSU threads, receiving feedback is awesome... :)
>   – Tom Wijsman

Now I've been thinking of a way of getting some feedback from fellow users on a thread that is meant for that purpose. I had the following idea and was wondering if such a thing would be appropriate on Meta.SU and if there are other users that would welcome receiving feedback.

A question on which every user that wants feedback/comments can place an answer for him/herself. Other users are then asked to place comments on that answer with some short form of feedback. An example answer would be:

> > ### BloodPhilia
> >
> > Please give me some feedback!

> > *Comments:*
> >
> > > - *I think BloodPhilia is xxx and does a xxx job. What he does well: xxx What he doesn't do so well: xxx*
> > > - *Bloodphila is a horrible user and he should be banned for all of eternity!*
> > > - *etc.*

Comment: We can't do eternity but we'll certainly shoot for it

Comment: @random That would be a bummer! :(

Comment: Yeah I think the limit is like _`some ridiculous number of years`_ or something like that. Will that be enough for you? :P

Comment: @nhinkle As long as you get that awful user out of here!

Comment: I think chat would be a better platform.. perhaps have a weekly event or somelike.

Comment: @Sathya Yes I agree it would fit better there, but it wouldn't give a nice overview on a user's feedback per user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not *entirely* sure what the purpose of this would be; we prefer to focus on posts rather than the person.

However, if you want to do something like this, it is OK on meta -- anything involving the community is explicitly on topic here.

Still a bit unusual though, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

While on-topic for meta I don't think it's the most constructive.  What purpose would this really serve?  If it's to help users improve I see comments on the questions or answers that they post as the best place for this or in certain situations, chat can be used.  If it's for compliments, again, while it induces a great feeling, it's not entirely useful to the site IMO.

If we have a place where anyone can be complimented, then what does a yearly contest like ours really accomplish?  MVSU and the other rewards associated with the Super Contest are meant to do just that, compliment and reward users for their hard work and dedication to Super User.  If this was done on a consistent basis, then the lure for the Super Contest becomes more for the prizes and not for the recognition.

My personal opinion is that we should generally avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest having in user profiles instead - it seems a natural place for it

Comment: No, then you get like a public alternative of the user annotations that moderators have, we shouldn't put it up front in public...

Comment: the first rule of user annotations is... ;p