# Historical significance lock reason on answers still states "this question"

Tags: bug, locked, post-notice

While the content dispute and off-topic comments lock reasons use a more general term ("this post"), the historical significance lock reason *on both questions and answers* still states:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: [help center](https://superuser.com/help/).

(https://meta.superuser.com/a/3216/)

This makes perfect sense on questions, but is confusing on *answers*. I propose that the lock reason for answers states instead:

> This answer exists because it has historical significance, but **it does not attempt to answer the question asked**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can post similar answers here. This answer and its comments are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: [help center](https://superuser.com/help).

Comment: @Sathya It's a feature request because of the proposed new notice for answers. And [meta-tag:locked] is apparently the only tag that deals with locked questions.

Comment: it's either a bug or a feature request, not both.

Comment: @Sathya Okay, I can see why it's not a feature request. Oh, and I meant locked *posts* in my other comment.